# Spring Expression Language (SpEL) for Array Method Parameters

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

I have a Spring Integration project where I am trying to call a method on a bean that takes a `String` object and `Class` object as parameters. The class object I want to pass to it is `Long[].class` but I can't figure out the correct syntax. I've tried various combinations of the following to no avail:

```
expression="@parser.readValue(payload, T(java.lang.Long[]))"
```

For now I've simply wrapped the call in another java class (hardcoding the `Class` type) and call that via SpEL. What is the correct syntax for an array class parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works...

```
...(payload, new java.lang.Long[0].class)
```

Comment: FYI, SPR-9203 is now committed and will be available in Spring Framework 3.2 M1.